# How to use PHP on file_get_contents data

Tags: php, html

I have an email I am generating

I have a file that is generating styles and some complex data

```
$_SESSION["conUUID"]=$uuid;
$body = file_get_contents('getemail.php');
```

in the getemail.php I start with this:
yet none of this runs - it only shows my HTML underneath it

```
$conUUID = $_SESSION["conUUID"];
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo "session:";
        var_dump($_SESSION["conUUID"]);

        if($conUUID == null)
        {
            echo "Failure";
            die(2);
        }
        echo "hi";
        die(2);
```

How can I get dynamic data inside of this file?

Comment: why are you not using include?

Comment: @Dagon - what do you mean?

Comment: Umm.. Clearly I don't understand? Can you help me?
What do you mean include? Can you give me an example? If you look at my code above I have html being placed into a variable - how does include() put html in a variable?